# Approaching Typeahead.js prefatched datums

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm using Twitter Typeahead.js like this:

```
$('.autocomplete').typeahead({
  name: 'autocomplete',
  prefetch: https://localhost/datums.json
});
```

Is there any possibility how to approach datums.json values anywhere else in the script? Like creating a condition asking if some value exists in typeahead's datums.

Comment: yeah u have and event...initialized it will fire after prefetch is done, allso u can use source and to an ajax call and cache data there

Comment: yes, but those are working only inside typeahead object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for, you can use `local` instead of `prefetch`. Use an HTTP client (XMLHttpRequest, e.g.) to read `/datums.json` yourself, and store a reference to it in a variable. Then pass that variable as `local` to Typeahead.